# How to save a template as PDF in symfony

Tags: pdf, symfony1, symfony-1.4, template-engine

I am using Symfony1.4 with doctrine. I want to save a invoice template to PDF. How can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

I use for this [**sfTCPDFPlugin**](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin)

Comment: How can i save the entire template as such

Comment: I'm also using sfTCPDFPlugin, in my template i have dotted lines as borders and font size also differs while saving as pdf

Comment: Hm, you can save for example : `$pdf->Output('./invoice/'.$invoice_name.'.pdf', 'F');`Much depends on font,which you use. You can set it:`$pdf->SetFont('dejavusanscondensed', '', 10);' You can see many examples in [tcpdf.org](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)

Answer (score 0):

For converting HTML to PDF, I get the best results with [Wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Because it uses the Webkit rendering engine (the same used in Chrome and Safari for example), the results are exactly the way you can see the HTML rendered in those browsers.

It is in fact just a binary you can run from the command-line, but an example PHP wrapper class is available from the website. I also did not find it very hard to write a wrapper class myself with some added functionality.